# debugging virtual function

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QT to develop c++ code. I define my virtual function in my inhereted class. but when I want to debug, the debugger doesn't go inside of my function. I mean when I am at this line:

```
 myClassInstance->Foo(SujectNum,Subjects);
```

and I press F11 to step into `Foo` function, it doesn't go inside, although I put breakpoint inside function.
how should I debug this function ?

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Try setting the break-point to the file, where the real called function is defined. Like (gdb)b MyClassImpl.cpp:123

Comment: where I should put this in qt: (gdb)b MyClassImpl.cpp ?

Comment: system? IDE name? if windows do you used visual studio or gcc? 32/64 bits?

Comment: it is fedora with QT Creator

Comment: One line of code is not enough to understand the issue.  Could you post a complete example?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're not overriding the correct method. Make sure that your headers add the `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` keyword after the *declaration* of each overriden method, and you compile using a C++11 compiler. Add `CONFIG += c++11` to your project file.

```
#if __cplusplus > 199711L
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#define Q_DECL_OVERRIDE override
#endif
#else
#error You need a C++11 compiler to compile this code.
#endif

class Foo : public Bar {
public:
  void foo(int index, const QList<Subject> & subjects) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  ...
};
```

Comment: when I add `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` to function decleration, I get `unexpected token: Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` syntax error

Comment: @user667222 You must be using Qt 4, then. See the edit.

Comment: well, I override the virtual function in `Foo` class but when I press F2 on `foo` function of created instance of `Foo`, it referes to the foo function of the `Bar` class not `Foo` class

Comment: @user667222 It's likely that you're facing [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). Add a self-contained example to your question.